# xampp #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

i tried to open my local Xampp to work on some projects, but when i go on Phpmyadmin and try to access to any database i retrieve the error message in the object.

I have to backup some db in every way because they are very important.

I tried to delete the pma_bookmark.frm and .ibd and then create again creates_table.sql but it doesn't solve my problem.

How can i solve this issue, but more, how can i save my databases and reload them on another installation or in another server ?

Comment: Please do never delete raw database files! Delete databases and tables through MySQL cli or phpMyAdmin, but never files you find on your disk!

Comment: I found it in a post here on Stackoverflow

Comment: Now, how can i solve it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma\_\_tracking' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist)

Comment: in order to execute that script, i have to change some data like db_name ? Because it give me "No database selected"

Comment: Just execute `USE phpmyadmin` before the other script

Comment: I did it but it says again that "phpmyadmin.pma_tracking doesn't exist in engine" but i see that in the folder mysql/data inside the phpmyadmin folder it exists

Comment: So have another try at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543851/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist-how-to-disable-manually - probably, you can disable the tracking feature alltogether?

Comment: I tried to execute the create_tables, I tried to disable the statement "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking']" but it isn't still working